# How can I use Multi Media Uploader in the WordPress Plugins?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I try to add the multi uploading options in the wordpress plugins I repeated this code in the plugin(two times) only changing the id name.

```
                    <script language="JavaScript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
        formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
        tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');
        return false;
    });

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        imgurl = jQuery('img', html).attr('src');
        jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
        tb_remove();
    };

});
                    </script>
<input id="upload_image" style=" margin-left:303px;" type="text" size="36" name="upload_image_template" value="<?php echo get_option('upload_image_template'); ?>" />
                        <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Browse" />
```

Whenever I try to upload a image that media frame comes and the uploading process are did successfully. But Insert Into Post fetch the correct url but pasted in different input box.
For example:

```
1) [text box1] [browse Button]
2) [text box2] [browse button]
```

When I upload image with Text Box One that `[insert post]` that image path is shown in `[text box 2]`
I am Not Sure Whether the Problem is mine or that script didn't support multi file upload option.

Comment: Could you post the code for both input boxes?

Comment: You may be interested in this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-image-upload/

Comment: Thanks @TahirYasin I look at the plugin this what i want. Thanks for sharing I am gonna give as five star rating  in wordpress

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is the example how you can use the wordpress multimedia uploader for more than one field or as many fields. The `JS` code and html code looks like this

### How it works

Add `upload_image_button` class on each upload button on the basis of this class `click` function triggers to fetch the wordpress multimedia uploader , see i have used the `prev()` property to get the previous element to the clicked one `formfieldID=jQuery(this).prev().attr("id");`  and then i have assigned the image url returned by uploader to `formfieldID`

```
 <input id="upload_image1" type="text" name="upload_image1" value="<?php echo $upload_image1;?>" />
    <input class="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload image 1" />

<input id="upload_image2" type="text"  name="upload_image2" value="<?php echo $upload_image2;?>" />
    <input class="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload image 2" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    //tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?TB_iframe=true');
    var upload_image_button=false;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.upload_image_button').click(function() {
        upload_image_button =true;
        formfieldID=jQuery(this).prev().attr("id");
     formfield = jQuery("#"+formfieldID).attr('name');
     tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
        if(upload_image_button==true){

                var oldFunc = window.send_to_editor;
                window.send_to_editor = function(html) {

                imgurl = jQuery('img', html).attr('src');
                jQuery("#"+formfieldID).val(imgurl);
                 tb_remove();
                window.send_to_editor = oldFunc;
                }
        }
        upload_image_button=false;
    });


    })

</script>
```

Also make sure you have included the necessary `JS` and `CSS` files of the uploader for this you have to add an action

```
<?php
function my_admin_uploader_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
wp_register_script('my-upload', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/my-script.js', array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox'));
wp_enqueue_script('my-upload');
}

function my_admin_uploader_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_admin_uploader_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'my_admin_uploader_styles'); 
?>
```

> Note: Also take care of one thing when you assign the uploader to
>   you input fields the control of uploader now assigns to the fields so
>   when ever uploader will be called it assigns the image url to your
>   text field , so this is the problem when you triggers the uploader you
>   are unable to insert the images in the content area of the post for
>   this solution you have to store the previous control in some where and
>   when you are done with uploader then reassign the control of uploader
>   to the previous function which i have provided in my JS code see below
>   how it works

```
 var oldFunc = window.send_to_editor;
                    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {

                    imgurl = jQuery('img', html).attr('src');
                    jQuery("#"+formfieldID).val(imgurl);
                     tb_remove();
                    window.send_to_editor = oldFunc;
                    }
```

I have used this technique many times and it works perfect for me

Hope it makes sense

Comment: How can i use this with multi thumbnail? [Like this, but multiple thumbnail.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668899/how-to-add-the-media-uploader-in-wordpress-plugin/23701719#23701719)

Comment: @BrianS If you have a question then please ask new one

Comment: Why should i ask a new one? When my question is relative to this one? @MKhalidJunaid

Comment: @BrianS because this answer covers the scope of OP's question if i edit the answer this will change the scope thats why i have asked if you have a question then ask new one

Comment: gotcu, sorry I'm new to here... i already solve my problem by myself.

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid it is work perfectly without any problem. in some template admin panel directly after upload image and click on Insert to post show the image without refresh page but in my plugin after insert the image url in to my input file must click on save changes and refresh page then show me the image.

Comment: Not sure what my issue is, but imgurl returns as 'undefined'

Comment: nvm. I had to change `imgurl = jQuery('img', html).attr('src');` to `imgurl = jQuery(html).attr('src');`. `html` was only returning the <img> element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code based on [Codex wp.media Example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media)

**Javascript**

```
var sfieldGroup= '.field-group';   // top level parent  

var wpMediaUploader = { 
            sBtnAdd : ".upload-custom-wp-media",
            sBtnRemove : ".remove-custom-wp-media",
            sMediaData: ".media-data",
            sInput : ".custom-wp-media"
        };

 function wpMedia() {
        $(wpMediaUploader.sBtnAdd).on("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var self = $(this);
            var fieldGroup = self.parents(sfieldGroup);

            // Create a new media frame
            var frame = wp.media({
                title: "Select or Upload Media Of Your Chosen Persuasion",
                button: {
                    text: "Use this media"
                },
                multiple: false  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
            });

            frame.on("select", function () {
                var attachment = frame.state().get("selection").first().toJSON();

                switch(attachment.mime){
                    case "image/jpeg" :
                    case "image/png" :
                    case "image/bmp" :
                    case "image/gif" :
                        fieldGroup.find(wpMediaUploader.sMediaData)
                            .append("<img src=\"" + attachment.url + "\" alt=\"\" />");
                        break;
                }

                $("<p/>",{
                    text: attachment.filename
                }).appendTo(fieldGroup.find(wpMediaUploader.sMediaData));

                fieldGroup.find(wpMediaUploader.sInput).val(attachment.id);
                fieldGroup.find(wpMediaUploader.sBtnAdd).addClass("hidden");
                fieldGroup.find(wpMediaUploader.sBtnRemove).removeClass("hidden");

                frame.close();
            });

            frame.open();
        });


        $(wpMediaUploader.sBtnRemove).on("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var self = $(this);
            var fieldGroup = self.parents(sfieldGroup); 


            // Clear out the preview image
            fieldGroup.find(wpMediaUploader.sMediaData).html("");

            // Un-hide the add image link
            fieldGroup.find(wpMediaUploader.sBtnAdd).removeClass("hidden");

            // Hide the delete image link
            fieldGroup.find(wpMediaUploader.sBtnRemove).addClass("hidden");

            // Delete the image id from the hidden input
            fieldGroup.find(wpMediaUploader.sInput).val("");
        });
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="field-group">
    <div class="media-data"></div>
    <p class="hide-if-no-js">
        <a class="button upload-custom-wp-media" href="javascript:void(0)">Upload Media</a>
        <a class="button remove-custom-wp-media hidden" href="javascript:void(0)">Remove Selected Media</a>
    </p>
    <input id="test" name="test" class="custom-wp-media" value="" type="hidden">
</div>
```

*Tip*
if you console.log frame,you will be exposed to API :)

```
            var frame = wp.media({
                title: "Select or Upload Media Of Your Chosen Persuasion",
                button: {
                    text: "Use this media"
                },
                multiple: false  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
            });
```

Comment: Don't forget to add: ```add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function() { wp_enqueue_media(); }```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't that hard...

See this revision history to see how I did...
Basically what I did was adding this to my plugin:

```
function wp_gear_manager_admin_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

function wp_gear_manager_admin_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}

add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'wp_gear_manager_admin_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'wp_gear_manager_admin_styles');
```

And later this part in my JavaScript file:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');
return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
tb_remove();
}

});
</script>
```

And this in my html:

```
<tr valign="top">
    <td>Upload Image</td>
    <td><label for="upload_image">
        <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="upload_image" value="<?php echo $gearimage; ?>" />
        <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
        <br />Enter an URL or upload an image for the banner.
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can just copy and paste this code to your plugin and see the magic.

Comment: "and later this part"  - later when?  where?  in which file?

Answer (score 0):

Here, for the edit image to work, also to show other filter, hope it helps.

```
pa_uploader = wp.media({ 
            title: 'Choose Images',
            multiple: true,
            //frame: 'select',
            library: {
                filterable: 'all',
                editable: true,
                contentUserSetting: false
            },
            states: [
                new wp.media.controller.Library({
                    id:         'library',
                    title:      'Select Images',
                    priority:   40,
                    // toolbar:    'gallery',
                    filterable: 'all',
                    multiple:   'add',
                    editable:   true,
                    contentUserSetting: false,
                    library:  wp.media.query( _.defaults({
                        type: 'image'
                    }, {} ) )
                }),
                new wp.media.controller.EditImage({model: {}})
            ]
        });
       // pa_uploader.states.add([
       //       new wp.media.controller.EditImage({model: {}})
       //   ]);

        pa_uploader.on('content:render:edit-image', function() {
            var controller = pa_uploader.modal.controller;
                image = pa_uploader.state().get('image'),
                view = new wp.media.view.EditImage( { model: image, controller: controller } ).render();

            pa_uploader.content.set( view );

            // after creating the wrapper view, load the actual editor via an ajax call
            view.loadEditor();
        });
        pa_uploader.on('select', function(e){
            // This will return the selected image from the Media Uploader, the result is an object
            var selected_images = pa_uploader.state().get('selection');

                });
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer from M Khalid Junaid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17754881/782013) is great but outdated.

See the codex page about wp.media : https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media.