# How to add the media uploader in wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I read out some of the tutorial for how to integrate the media uploader in wordpress plugins. I do the media uploader based on the tutorial. 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/howto-integrate-the-media-library-into-a-plugin?replies=4
 I do this and it perfectly working. When i tried the same script again for multiple times of media uploader, Here is the fiddle i tried simply changed the id of the particular text field.
http://jsfiddle.net/UrXPe/1/ 
Still when i click the upload all is to be to done perfect. only thing if i click `insert into post` it url of the image appear in the second browse field. Here is the screenshot what i face exactly.
[image]

When i click the first upload field (uploading process are success) after insert into post that corresponding media url is appear in the second field not in first. I am not sure where is the problem any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**UPDATED - scroll down**

After too much of hard work and research and some customization I coded below compact few lines of code to use media uploader anywhere in wordpress. Just put code in some function and call that function wherever you want.
The path of uploaded/selected file will be copied to text-box and then you can use it.

```
// jQuery
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
// This will enqueue the Media Uploader script
wp_enqueue_media();
?>
    <div>
    <label for="image_url">Image</label>
    <input type="text" name="image_url" id="image_url" class="regular-text">
    <input type="button" name="upload-btn" id="upload-btn" class="button-secondary" value="Upload Image">
   
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#upload-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var image = wp.media({ 
            title: 'Upload Image',
            // mutiple: true if you want to upload multiple files at once
            multiple: false
        }).open()
        .on('select', function(e){
            // This will return the selected image from the Media Uploader, the result is an object
            var uploaded_image = image.state().get('selection').first();
            // We convert uploaded_image to a JSON object to make accessing it easier
            // Output to the console uploaded_image
            console.log(uploaded_image);
            var image_url = uploaded_image.toJSON().url;
            // Let's assign the url value to the input field
            $('#image_url').val(image_url);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE**: Just to add. You may need to add the function wrapper in your plugin/theme file. This is the following:

```
// UPLOAD ENGINE
function load_wp_media_files() {
    wp_enqueue_media();
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_wp_media_files' );
```

This will call the relevant JS files and CSS files if WP fails to load the upload manager. This also removes console warnings.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I tried it on a popup but it didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500327/launching-media-uploader-in-wordpress-from-another-popup .

Comment: Hello can u tell me how can I store this image path to database of word press and retrieve this image later on

Comment: thanks user3337553! @rupesh store it as a custom option, have a look here http://tinyurl.com/pz3v9jx

Comment: Any way to force this to default to the upload view instead of whatever view was used last? Awesome code btw. Thank you.

Comment: This works like a charm for one image, but how do you do multiples? I enables the multiple: true, which seems to allow multiple selected, but how can I make those image URIs show up in other text boxes?

Comment: Removing .first() from image.state().get('selection'), convert to JSON and then loop through uploaded_image variable should do the trick. @Articulous

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this method to use media uploader into my custom plugin.May be this would be help.

in the **main theme file(index.php)** add these.

```
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox'); // call to media files in wp
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
wp_enqueue_script( 'media-upload'); 


// load script to admin
function wpss_admin_js() {
     $siteurl = get_option('siteurl');
     $url = $siteurl . '/wp-content/plugins/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/js/admin_script.js';
     echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='$url'></script>"; 
}
 add_action('admin_head', 'wpss_admin_js');
```

In the **admin_script.js** file,

```
jQuery('#wpss_upload_image_button').click(function() {
    formfield = jQuery('#wpss_upload_image').attr('name');
    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
    return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
 jQuery('#wpss_upload_image').val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();

 jQuery('#wpss_upload_image_thumb').html("<img height='65' src='"+imgurl+"'/>");
}
```

**admin file(admin_settings.php),**

```
<div id="wpss_upload_image_thumb" class="wpss-file">
    <?php if(isset($record->security_image) && $record->security_image !='') { ?>
       <img src="<?php echo $record->security_image;?>"  width="65"/><?php } else {    echo $defaultImage; } ?>
</div>
<input id="wpss_upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="wpss_upload_image" value="" class="wpss_text wpss-file" />
<input id="wpss_upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" class="wpss-filebtn" />
```

More details [in my blog](http://webexplorar.com/how-to-use-media-uploader-in-wordpress-custom-plugin/)

Comment: How do you use this for multiple uploading?

Comment: You can follow this instructions.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320802/how-can-i-use-multi-media-uploader-in-the-wordpress-plugins

Comment: Any idea on how I can remedy my situation inside a popup, @SumithHarshan? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500327/launching-media-uploader-in-wordpress-from-another-popup

Comment: thickbox is deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your custom plugin

```
<label for="upload_image">
    <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="ad_image" value="http://" /> 
    <input id="upload_image_button" class="button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
    <br />Enter a URL or upload an image
</label>

<?php
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');

function my_admin_scripts() {
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'my_plugin_page') {
        wp_enqueue_media();
        wp_register_script('my-admin-js', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/my-plugin/my-admin.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('my-admin-js');
    }
}

?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){


    var custom_uploader;


    $('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }

        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose Image',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Image'
            },
            multiple: true
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
            console.log(custom_uploader.state().get('selection').toJSON());
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $('#upload_image').val(attachment.url);
        });

        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();

    });


});
    </script>
```