# Create upload field in Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm starting my first new plugin, and as a test, I pretend to create a field in my plugin admin (back-end) where the user can upload an image, and that image will appear on the header of my main wordpress page (front-end).

My question: how can I upload images through my plugin? And later on, how can I make that image appear in my front-end?

If someone could just head me to the right direction, I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ref uploader](http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/) to upload media in your plugin. as here:

[How to add the media uploader in wordpress plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668899/how-to-add-the-media-uploader-in-wordpress-plugin)