# Wordpress: Upload Image in Admin Options Page

Tags: php, wordpress, image, forms, upload

I am developing my first wordpress plugin.  It only needs to allow a user to change a logo in a custom template and change a color scheme in the custom template.

I have made an admin options page and now want to add a field to allow a user to upload an image.  How can I upload an image to the wp-content/uploads folder.  So far, I have this within a table:

```
<td><input name="logo_image" type="file" id="logo_image" value="" /></td>
```

Is this the right approach?  If so, how do I direct the file to the right folder?  Doesn't wordpress have it's own way of handling file uploads?

Comment: It will create the upload media directory as empty,but is not rendering the default media popup section

Answer (score 24):

**Add this code to your global custom option function.**

```
if(function_exists( 'wp_enqueue_media' )){
    wp_enqueue_media();
}else{
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
}

<p><strong>Header Logo Image URL:</strong><br />
                <img class="header_logo" src="<?php echo get_option('header_logo'); ?>" height="100" width="100"/>
                <input class="header_logo_url" type="text" name="header_logo" size="60" value="<?php echo get_option('header_logo'); ?>">
                <a href="#" class="header_logo_upload">Upload</a>

</p>    


<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.header_logo_upload').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var custom_uploader = wp.media({
                title: 'Custom Image',
                button: {
                    text: 'Upload Image'
                },
                multiple: false  // Set this to true to allow multiple files to be selected
            })
            .on('select', function() {
                var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                $('.header_logo').attr('src', attachment.url);
                $('.header_logo_url').val(attachment.url);

            })
            .open();
        });
    });
</script>
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847714/wordpress-3-5-custom-media-upload-for-your-theme-options)

or

[Media uploader in theme and plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668899/how-to-add-the-media-uploader-in-wordpress-plugin)

[image]

Comment: not sure where to add this... The admin menu is a php file, do i simply add the JS part ??

Comment: this one depend on your function for your setting. how to create look hear
https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Comment: from what i understand - wordpress recommends using the customizer API instead...  https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the inbuilt function of wordpress

```
<?php wp_handle_upload( $file, $overrides, $time ); ?>
```

This will automatically move the file to the uploads folder

Or

You can write your own `PHP` function.

Additional Details can be found here -> [Wordpress File Upload](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload)