# Wordpress wp.media Upload image

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, upload

Ok here is my code - stock standard and *works if I simply select an existing image*

```
 jQuery(function($){
 var file_frame;

 $('#upload-button').on( 'click', function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
      // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
if ( file_frame ) {
  file_frame.open();
  return;
}
 // Create a new media frame
file_frame = wp.media({
  title: 'Select or Upload Media Of Your Chosen Persuasion',
  button: {
    text: 'Use this media'
  },
  multiple: false  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
});

 file_frame.on('open', function(){
     console.log("inside open");

 });
    file_frame.on('update', function(){
     console.log("inside update");
 });
file_frame.on('select', function(){

        // This will return the selected image from the Media Uploader, the result is an object
        var uploaded_image = file_frame.state().get('selection').first();
        // We convert uploaded_image to a JSON object to make accessing it easier
        // Output to the console uploaded_image
        console.log(uploaded_image);
        var image_url = uploaded_image.toJSON().url;
        // Let's assign the url value to the input field
        $('#image-url').val(image_url);
    });
    file_frame.open();
});
});
```

But if I goto drag and drop an image in there the image is uploaded but an error is returned
**"An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."**

What have I missed, I'm assuming its some kind of refresh for the existing   media selection window and my googling has not turned up anything.

Cheers

**EDIT**

I have tried several things to get the uploaded image to be shown in the media frame once uploaded. Not having much success.
As I said it appears the image is uploaded and added to the media library but I am missing a refresh or reload of the frame to show the image.

Any one have experience with or know another place to go look?

Comment: It's for of front or back form ?

Comment: back end form. specifically a plugin I am writing.

Comment: try this code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874469/wordpress-upload-image-in-admin-options-page/22876571#22876571

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this call when everything is 'done':

```
if(wp.media.frame.library) wp.media.frame.library.props.set({ignore: (+ new Date())});
```

Or if you need to *separate* the *library Grid modal* from *media upload (edit post) modal*:

```
if(wp.media.frame.library){
    wp.media.frame.library.props.set({ignore: (+ new Date())});
  } else if(wp.media.frame.content.get().collection){
    wp.media.frame.content.get().collection.props.set({ignore: (+ new Date())});
    wp.media.frame.content.get().options.selection.reset();
}
```